# Firefox webextension - confirm function causes extension popup to close immediately

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I would like to port an existing fully functional *Chrome* extension to *Firefox*, everything seems to work except the `confirm()` function behavior.

When the user clicks a specific button in the popup.html page, he is asked to confirm the action.

*Chrome* successfully prompts the dialog, I then get a Boolean back as soon as "ok" or "cancel" button is clicked, code related to the boolean returned is executed.

*Firefox* behavior feels buggy on the other hand. The confirm dialog prompts too but the extension popup is instantly dismissed, preventing further code in the click event handler to execute.

*manifest.json* : `…, "default_popup": "popup.html", …`

*popup.html* :

```
  …
  <script src="js/popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

*popup.js* :

```
removeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  // Firefox: calling confirm() closes the popup.html page ...
  // ... terminating event handler code
  if (confirm("Please confirm you wish to remove this item.")) {
    // …
  }
});
```

Is there something to do about it or should I stop using `confirm()` and find a workaround ?

### EDIT - Workaround solution

As a workaround, I set a 3 seconds countdown when the button is clicked and change its caption every second. Before time is up, if the user click again, the final action gets cancelled, otherwise final action is performed.

```js
let log = document.querySelector('p')
    ,resetInterval = null
    ;
document.getElementById('resetbtn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!resetInterval) {
      // Create a countdown and delete data when time is up.
      e.target.content = e.target.innerHTML;
      resetInterval = setInterval( function() {
          var counter = +(e.target.innerHTML.trim().match(/\d+/)||[4])[0];
          if (counter == 1) {
              // Sending command to bacground page
              // chrome.runtime.sendMessage({command:'remove'}, function (){
              e.target.innerHTML = e.target.content;
              resetInterval && clearInterval(resetInterval);
              resetInterval = null;
              log.innerHTML = 'Perform action…';
              // });
          } else e.target.innerHTML = 'Reset in '+(counter-1)+'s';
      }, 1000);
      log.innerHTML = '';
  } else {
      resetInterval && clearInterval(resetInterval);
      e.target.innerHTML = e.target.content;
      resetInterval = null;
      log.innerHTML = 'Action aborted';
  }
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="resetbtn">Reset</button>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Don't use these ancient js modal dialogs in FF. Implement your own or use an existing library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popout windows are designed to be dismissed when you move focus to another window. You can’t use dialogs (new windows) from the popout as they’re moving focus and thus dismissing the popout.